# Get original rectangle bounds from rotated rectangle(resized) and rotation angle

Tags: matrices, transformation, rectangles

Is there any possible way to reverse a rotated rectangle rotation, get the bounds before rotation.

I have the rotated rectangle (Resized after rotation) value and the rotation angle, and I would like to calculate the original rectangle value before rotation.

Is this possible

Comment: Do you know how precisely it was resized and rotated? i.e. about which point, by what angles/factors?

Comment: Yes, already know the center and rotate angle

Comment: What do you mean by “the rotated rectangle (Resided after rotation)?” Is this the axis-aligned bounding box of the rotated rectangle?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you say "resized", you mean resized about the same origin as the rotation? As an example, the rectangle $$1\le x\le 2,\ \ \ 1\le y\le 2$$ can be scaled about the origin by a factor of 2, yielding $$2\le x\le 4,\ \ \ 2\le y\le 4$$ or scaled by a factor of 2 about the point $(1, 1)$, yielding $$1\le x\le 3,\ \ \ 1\le y\le 3$$

Comment: I suggest adding a picture or two of the situation.